# Rewriting JavaScript to jQuery for compatibility reasons with first generation iPad running Safari

Tags: html, jquery

I am not an expert on JQuery. The following Javascript script works well with modern browsers. However when running it on a first generation ipad running Safari it does not work. According to documentation that I have read on this subject, it is suggested to use JQuery. Apparently a possible solution is to rewrite the script to JQuery for compatibility reasons. Consequently I need to convert this script to JQuery. The fetch ... instruction specifically makes a call to a route @app.route('/city/ ... which is written in Flask ... the essential idea is to rewrite the script in JQuery and not make modifications to the code in Flask. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
                        <!-- script for the dynamic selection of the names of the cities that correspond to the province -->
                        <script>
                            var province_select = document.getElementById("province_name");
                            var city_select = document.getElementById("city");

                            province_select.onchange = function()  {
                                
                                province = province_select.value;
                                
                                fetch('/city/' + province).then(function(response) {

                                    response.json().then(function(data) {
                                        
                                        var optionHTML = '';

                                        for (var city of data.cities) {
                                            
                                            optionHTML += '<option value="' + city.name_of_the_city + '">' + city.name_of_the_city + '</option>';
                                            
                                        }

                                        city_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                                    })
                                    
                                });
                            }
                        </script>
```

Attached is the polyfill implementation (not sure whether it is correct). I have not worked with polyfill:

```
<script>
var province_select = document.getElementById("province_name");
var city_select = document.getElementById("city");

// Detect if user is on IE browser or
// whether the user is using a browser that does not support fetch 
// SEE: https://dev.to/adrianbdesigns/how-to-polyfill-javascript-fetch-function-for-internet-explorer-g46

var isIE = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;

if (isIE) {
    // Create Promise polyfill script tag
    var promiseScript = document.createElement("script");
    promiseScript.type = "text/javascript";
    promiseScript.src =
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8.1.3/dist/polyfill.min.js";

    // Create Fetch polyfill script tag
    var fetchScript = document.createElement("script");
    fetchScript.type = "text/javascript";
    fetchScript.src =
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/whatwg-fetch@3.4.0/dist/fetch.umd.min.js";

    // Add polyfills to head element
    document.head.appendChild(promiseScript);
    document.head.appendChild(fetchScript);

    // Wait for the polyfills to load and run the function. 

    setTimeout(function () {
        window
            .fetch('/city/' + province).then(function(response) {

                response.json().then(function(data) {
                    
                    var optionHTML = '';

                    for (var city of data.cities) {
                        
                        optionHTML += '<option value="' + city.name_of_the_city + '">' + city.name_of_the_city + '</option>';
                        
                    }

                    city_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                })
                
            })

            .then(handleResponse)
            .catch(handleErrors);
    }, 1000);


} else {

    // If fetch is supported, just run the fetch function
    
    province_select.onchange = function()  {
        
        province = province_select.value;
        
        fetch('/city/' + province).then(function(response) {

            response.json().then(function(data) {
                
                var optionHTML = '';

                for (var city of data.cities) {
                    
                    optionHTML += '<option value="' + city.name_of_the_city + '">' + city.name_of_the_city + '</option>';
                    
                }

                city_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
            })
            
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You could just add a fetch polyfill instead of using jQuery which isn't needed in the first place. All you need to do is use an older method for fetching you data from the api (ajax, XMLHttpRequest, axios).

Comment: @ thetailer.de - I have implemented polyfill using the instructions I found in this article: "How to polyfill JavaScript fetch function for Internet Explorer". https://dev.to/adrianbdesigns/how-to-polyfill-javascript-fetch-function-for-internet-explorer-g46

Comment: @ thetailer.de - The tests I have carried out are on a first generation ipad that has Safari as a browser. The results are not positive. I have no experience using polyfill. Please could you check if the polyfill implementation is correct? Possibly it only evaluates by Internet Explorer and is not evaluating by Safari. Any help in this regard or guidance will be appreciated. What possibility is there that you can implement polyfill in the original code? Thank you.

Comment: replace the check `var isIE = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;` with `var isLegacy = 'fetch' in window;`. After that replace all `isIE` with `isLegacy` and in theory it should work.